# Location of spam injection links

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, code-injection, spam

Thanks for viewing,

I have a problem whereby a site that I help out at has had their affiliate links redirected to another affiliate id.

Here is the page in question: https://www.inafarawayland.com/10-day-itinerary-south-island-new-zealand/

The link in the bottom section to 'Rental Cars' is the bad link.

This only redirects to a foreign affiliate id when clicking. CMD-click goes to the correct affiliate id.

I've scoured the entire sites html, css and js code to find anything but I'm at lose ends.

What I think is happening is that there's a function searching for outgoing links with the correct id and replacing it with the foreign id.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you described sounds like an XSS-Attack. I've noticed, that the site features a comment section, so you might want to look for any `<script>` elements, or "onload" events and then remove any further such attacks in the processing of those comments.

I myself could, unfortunately, not replicate the error you described, assuming you meant the following link:

> https://www.motorhomerepublic.com/new-zealand/christchurch-motorhome-rental?affiliate=inafarawayland

If my guess turns out to be correct, I advice you to disarm the attacks on the backend rather than the frontend.

Comment: Thanks so much PixelRayn. You were right, it was in the comments section (where I found much more malware embedded). The solution was pretty simple, on Disqus (the comment hosting service) we disabled the ability for viewers to add certain elements into their comments. I also have no idea why this is even an option on Disqus. I think it was the introduction of small 1px by 1px images that contained the auto redirect. Thanks again for helping. Now we have to try and claim the missing revenue back from Admitad. Have a good weekend.